# How to determine how reliable my logistic regression probability is?

Tags: probability, logistic

When building a logistic regression, the probability of an observation belonging to a class can be calculated. But is there a way to determine how reliable that probability is? If the accuracy is of the model is low then how good is the probability?

Comment: I think this depends on how you would want to look at the "reliability" of the probability. Would you like a Confidence interval for the probability? Then maybe this will help: https://druedin.com/2016/01/16/predicted-probabilities-in-r/ or google some more on "confidence interval for predicted probabilitys" Or you kan just use the misclassification rate of your model to indicate the uncertainty. I hope this helps

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Measuring accuracy of a logistic regression-based model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18178/28500).